# DisposableBean.destroy() Vs ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed

Tags: java, spring, wildfly

In one of my service class, I am using `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(size)` as an ExecutorService. I am using the bean through out in my application then at the end i am shutting down the FixedThreadPool by Extending ContextLoaderListener class and calling the destroy method of service class from its `contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent)` method

but i can also shutdown the ExecutorService directly from service class by implementing `DisposableBean` interface and calling shutDown in its destroy() method.

so will there be any difference in the above two approaches and which one will be better to use for the graceful shutdown/redeployment of the web-app.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should be using `DisposableBean` (or you can specify a custom
destroy-method, no difference between those approaches).

The first reason is that it's more logical to do so because this is the responsibility of the `Bean` and not the `Context`. The second and even more important reason is that with your `contextDestroyed` approach you might make your `Service` unusable while it's still being used by other `Beans`.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental difference is DisposableBean is for specific bean and using ContextLoaderListener is for entire WebApplicationContext. So it depends what you want to do. as per docs

1. Using ContextLoaderListener contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event):
   Close the root web application context. [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html)
2. Using DisposableBean destroy method:
   Invoked by a BeanFactory on destruction of a singleton.Instead of this you can take a look at @PreDestroy annotation if you dont want to implement spring specific interface.